# Unable to get exact values on another intent using simpleadapter

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hey guys i am using a custom list adapter class that extends to simpleadapter for populating a multicolumn listview. I set onclick listener event on each of the textview in a column but I am unable to retrieve the values from that row associated with that textview and all its elements to another intent where I want to show data. Now on implementing this code I am getting random integers instead of correct values of the textview that was clicked.

this is my custom list adapter.java class

```
package com.example.category_wise_colored_newreport;


public class CustomList_adapter extends SimpleAdapter{

private List<Map<String, Object>> itemList;
//private ArrayList<HashMap<String , String>> itemList;
private Context mContext;
String ofc_code="ofc_code ";
String ofc_desg="ofc_desg ";
String ofc_name="ofc_name ";
String dep_name="dep_name ";
String total_comp="total_comp ";
String pending="pending ";
String desposed="disposed ";
String interim="interim ";
String defaulter="defaulter ";
String diposed_perc="disposed_percent ";
String TAG_COLOR1="color1";
String TAG_COLOR2="color2";
String TAG_COLOR3="color3";
String TAG_COLOR4="color4";
String TAG_COLOR5="color5";
ViewHolder holder=null;

public CustomList_adapter(Context context,
        List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from,
        int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.itemList=(List<Map<String,Object>>) data;
    this.mContext=context;
}


class ViewHolder
{
    TextView code;
    TextView desg;
    TextView name;
    TextView dep;
    TextView comp;
    TextView pend;
    TextView disp;
    TextView intr;
    TextView defl;
    TextView dispper;
}


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_routes, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();

       holder.code=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_content);
       holder.desg=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contet2);
       holder.name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contet3);
       holder.dep=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contet4);
       holder.comp=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contet5);
       holder.disp=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contet6);
       holder.pend=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contet7);
       holder.intr=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contet8);
       holder.defl=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contet9);
       holder.dispper=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contet10);
       holder.disp.setTag(position);
       holder.disp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Object pos= v.getTag();
            Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity2.class);
            //i.putExtra("X",holder.code.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("X",pos.toString());
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    });

       convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.code.setText((CharSequence)itemList.get(position).get(ofc_code));
    holder.desg.setText((CharSequence)itemList.get(position).get(ofc_desg));
    holder.name.setText((CharSequence)itemList.get(position).get(ofc_name));
    holder.dep.setText((CharSequence)itemList.get(position).get(dep_name));
    holder.comp.setText((CharSequence)itemList.get(position).get(total_comp));
    holder.disp.setText((CharSequence)itemList.get(position).get(desposed));
    holder.pend.setText((CharSequence)itemList.get(position).get(pending));
    holder.intr.setText((CharSequence)itemList.get(position).get(interim));
    holder.defl.setText((CharSequence)itemList.get(position).get(defaulter));
    holder.dispper.setText((CharSequence)itemList.get(position).get(diposed_perc));
    holder.disp.setBackgroundColor((Integer)itemList.get(position).get(TAG_COLOR1));
    holder.pend.setBackgroundColor((Integer)itemList.get(position).get(TAG_COLOR2));
    holder.intr.setBackgroundColor((Integer)itemList.get(position).get(TAG_COLOR3));
    holder.defl.setBackgroundColor((Integer)itemList.get(position).get(TAG_COLOR4));
    holder.dispper.setBackgroundColor((Integer)itemList.get(position).get(TAG_COLOR5));

    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `holder.disp.setTag(position);` to getView(). In onClick() retrieve position with `int position = v.getTag();`. (you need to cast something i think.).

Comment: bro @greenapps I tried your solution and I implemented it in my code. And I cast position like this Object position=v.getTage(); Then I parsed it into a string like this position.toString() and it throws a random integer each time. You can view my modified code.

Comment: Did you try: `int position = v.getTag();. (you need to cast something i think.).` ?

Comment: yeah bro @greenapps v.getTag() is to be casted .. I casted it into an integer. And after that when i click on the textview each textview gives me a random integer.

Comment: No you did not cast it to an integer. It does not look like i proposed. You put an int in so get it out.

Comment: you mean by "int in" i hav wrote this int pos=v.gettag(position). It shows a red line and asks me to change the modifier of position to final.

Comment: As said twice already start with `int position = v.getTag();`. And then add a cast if needed. Cast to int.

Comment: bro @greenapps if u want i can mail u the code. I am stuck in it  over a month

Comment: sorry bro @greenapps its working but giving me the wrong result everytime.

Comment: Show what you got please.

Comment: Add it to your code here so we can see what you tried.